# What are advantages and disadvantages in using VPS hosting vs standard Web hosting services?

Tags: web-hosting

I saw many companies offer Virtual Private Server hosting beside their Web Hosting packages.

I was wondering what are the differences, pros and contros.

Thanks

Answer (score 12, accepted):

**VPS ADVANTAGES**:

You are more in control with the server; it's virtual, but still you can manage it as a full server. You have **full root access**, full control and therefore you can do almost whatever you want installing anything you like, even stuff that is not provided the web hosting plans of the same provider, you **could remove the control panel and install another one** (i.e. removing cPanel and install webmin or remove totally a control panel and **manage the server by yourself changing manually the configuration**). You could replace the webmail interface with another one (i.e. remove Squirrelmail, and install something else). You can **change root Apache config https.conf and root php.ini config**.

**VPS DISADVANTAGES**:

You **MUST KNOW how to manage a server**; getting such know how is very time consuming, you need to learn and study carefully. You screw up something on a VPS and you risk it being unusable, or even worse, up and running but with dozens of SECURITY HOLES.
It's usually **more expensive** than a shared web hosting plan, but not always more expensive than a web hosting reseller plan.

**WEBHOSTING/RESELLER ADVANTAGES**:

You are in control only of what is already installed on the plan by the provider (i.e. cPanel for managing, Squirrelmail for web mail), even if you can still install your scripts and many third parties stuff. It's **much easier to manage**, and more difficult to be completely screwed up. If the server is down or there are security holes it's not your fault - you simply open a ticket and complain to the web host, who will have to take care about it.

You can **rewrite also Apache config for specific folder using the .htaccess file**. Also **php.ini config can be rewritten on a per-directory basis** because most web hosts install suPHP, which lets you rewrite php.ini config using a php.ini file in the directory you want it to be modified. It's definitely **cheaper**.

**WEBHOSTING/RESELLER DISADVANTAGES**:

If you want to change something at an higher level (like changing the control panel) you can't. You can NOT change root Apache config https.conf and root php.ini config.

---

Anyway there is still something missing here, and I'm missing it too. Many hosts are now selling FULLY MANAGED VPS; according to their policies these type of plans have the advantages of WEBHOSTING/RESELLER because if you screw up something, they look at it and they also prepare the server for you. It seems you don't require so much know how, but simply must careful not to put your hands where you shouldn't.

Actually I tried to ask a **similar question** on [serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/167859/hosting-cpanel-reseller-vs-cpanel-fully-managed-vps) you can find there also **links to other similar questions** that might help you too.

IMHO I don't understand **what's the catch for some hosts to push the VPS against the WEBHOSTING RESELLER plans**. Some hosters are even selling **FULLY MANAGED VPS at CHEAPER prices than RESELLER plans**. It seems bizarre because if I buy a VPS I'm probably going to open many more tickets to ask this & that and to ask them to fix/change something for me compared the the amount of tickets I could open with WEBHOSTING RESELLER plan.

Comment: ok. Yeah but (1) I guess it is cheaper because performances are lower than standard web hosting ? Is this true ? (2) Do I have access to httpd.conf and php.ini files in a VPS hosting service ?

Comment: Only on VPS you can access httpd.conf and php.ini, but on normal web hosting you can rewrite Apache config for spcific folder using the .htaccess file. Also php.ini config can be rewritten on a directories basis cause most web hoster install suPHP that let you rewrite php.ini config using a php.ini file in the directory you want it to be modified. You better obviously ask to the hoster a pre-sale question: "Do you have suPHP to allow me to rewrite php.ini configuration at a directory level. Do you also allow Apache rewrite engine to rewrite Apache config using .htacces"?

Comment: ok cool. One more question: can I also change some variables such as php memory limit (the PHP RAM) from the directory configuration if the hosting allows me to use directory level settings ?

Comment: I would say yes, always using php.ini on directory bases. I frequently change max_upload_size, max script time, etc. But suPHP must be installed. And the best thing is that you ask the hoster before you buy the plan, in this way you also see if it's a technically prepared hoster or just one of the many hidious hosters that think they need to know only few things to get up and run a server.

Answer (score 0):

Biggest advantage of virtual private server is the fact that you get simulation of dedicated hosting for fraction of a price.

I would say biggest advantage is isolation. You don't suffer the fact that you share server with hundreds of websites which can affect your website.

Biggest disadvantage can be complexity, but as someone mentioned with managed VPS hosting this is also turning inta advantage.

Answer (score 0):

A word of warning on VPS hosting.  Be sure to upgrade to a dedicated server before it gets too overloaded or you will suffer pain - trust me on this.

I have just completed such an upgrade and had allowed inodes to reach 90% and disk space was at 80% and it caused problems when it came to migrate.  In fact, the transfer had to be done slowly to not cause performance issues on the still running VPS web sites and it took 3 days to transfer 250Gb within the same data centre.

Remember that although you are on a VPS the V part is important.  You are sharing IO and other resources on the same server and they will be throttled to a certain point.

FWIW, the dedicated server has so much more breathing room in every area that it makes it much easier to manage.

Answer (score 0):

Their largest differences lay on two aspects:

1. VPS can allocate more disk space and monthly data transfer to you
   than web hosting, resulting in better security.
2. VPS allows you to have more control over the server via the Root
   access. Web hosting,however, only allows you to control your own
   websites.

In fact, these two hosting types are almost the same, for you are not own a dedicated server, but need to share the server resources with others. Difference only matters the number of your server neighborhoods. Therefore, no matter which hosting type you choose, you need to figure out whether this web host is reliable by checking its customer feedback on Google and its review on HostingReview360.