# Could you suggest a good VPS hosting for my own exercise?

Tags: web-hosting, vps

Could you suggest a good VPS hosting for my own exercise ?

I would like to have a server for development where I can have a lot of space, good performances and the ability to install my own software.

Also I would like to configure my apache and php configuration files as well, if possible?

PS. Not Microsoft software

Thanks

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Linode](http://www.linode.com/) are good if you need your server to be on all the time.  If you're only going to be firing it up every now and again then a cloud service like [Amazon EC2](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/) or the ones Thorn007 mentioned would be better.

Answer (score 4):

I highly recommend **Slicehost Servers** or **Rackspace Cloud Servers**. The two are both owned by the same company, Rackspace, but the payment methods differ.

I would check both of these out and see what fits your model best.

They have the best support you can dream of! **Total control Linux VPS machines**. You can do anything you want with these.

**Slicehost**: http://www.slicehost.com/

**Rackspace Cloud Servers**: http://www.rackspacecloud.com/cloud_hosting_products/servers

Comment: these type of new services seem interesting. So are they basically VPS where you pay an hourly fee based on server traffic, instead of paying a flat monthly/yearly fee? Did I understand properly? If yes don't you risk at the end of the month to pay more? In other type of services like Internet Service Providers usually a flat fee (expecially for internet connection) has always made me save so much on costs compared to a pay per hour fee. So I womder.

Comment: Slichost runs a monthly fee, like most places. The Rackspace Cloud Servers are the ones that make you pay for what you use. However, with the Rackspace Cloud Servers you will most likely end up paying less for massive bandwidth usage because, unlike other companies, there wouldn't be an overage fee. Again, Slicehost is monthly, Rackspace Cloud Servers are usage based. Depending on your needs one may be better than the other.

Answer (score 0):

In US I use this:  http://www.qualityhostonline.com

Dependending on the sofwtare you need to install you better evaluate the advantages to get a normal webhosting service rather than a VPS. [See your previous question](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/2434/whare-are-advantages-and-disadvantages-in-using-vps-hosting-vs-standard-web-hosti).

If your software is PHP script, PERL script written by you or third parties scripts/web apps (i.e. Wordpress, phpmail, swift mail, ...) you can do this perfectly buying a normal web hosting plan (and it's also cheaper).

ps1: YES FULL CONTROL! But many **Apache/PHP configurations can be also changed as well with a normal web hosting plan**. On cPanel (or other control panels) for instance you have many features that let you modify Apache handlers, MIME types, redirects, subdomain, etc. Moreover via FTP you can modify as you like the Apache .htaccess files in any one of your folders rewriting the Apache config with your rewrite rules. But true on web hosting you can NOT access the main Apache configuration, on a VPS you can, but think also that if you don't know what to do, it might be better you are not able to change the root Apache config. :)

ps2: only LINUX. :)

Answer (score 0):

your question sounds like you are rather new to running servers. if thats true, i would suggest you setup an old desktop or such at home because if you break something important you can just start over without any hustle.